# How to apply Contains( ) on a string array using LINQ to SQL c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, foreach, iqueryable

Good Day!

```
string[] keywords = toolStripTextBoxSearch.Text.Split(' ');
IQueryable<employee> query = db.employees;
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    query = query.Where(data => data.empName.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.bank.bankCode.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.bank.bankName.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.department.deptName.Contains(keyword)
                        || data.department.deptCode.ToString().Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.designation.desigText.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empBankAccount.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empBasicSalary.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empIncomeTax.ToString().Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empName.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empNTN.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.empTicketNumber.Contains(keyword) 
                        || data.grade.gradeText.Contains(keyword));
}

dataGridViewEmployee.DataSource = query;
```

Now if I write `"a b"` in the textbox, it shows no result while on writing "a" only or "b" only the gridview is showing multiple results.

Comment: you overwrite query every iteration with a new query, is the last keyword "b" or an empty character? at a quick guess you want `query.Where(d => keywords.Any(kw => data.empName.Contains(kw));`

Comment: The problem is that foreach keyword you are applying `AND`, so the result will be `(empName.Contains("a") OR empNTN.Contains("a") ...) AND (empName.Contains("b") OR empNTN.Contains("b") ...)` (because you are applying `Where` in a loop).

Comment: Can you better elaborate about the context and what you are trying to accomplish? For example you reference a gridview. Are you talking about an ASP.NET GridView or a winforms DataGridView. Can you show us some code that relates to it?

Comment: @Sayse your code encountered an exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Additional information: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett I'm working on winforms and having datagridview

Comment: @pwas yes, that's exactly what I am doing, now can you please let me know how can I change "AND" to OR?

Comment: Farhan, I didn't test it so its possible.. what does `keywords` contain? what should `a b` be returning? if its just those results that contain both then this should work.

Comment: I think I am unclear, Well.. I need to search a column from a table in the database that contains "a" or "b" not "a b"

space is just a separator

Comment: Hmm the fatest way I think is you use DynamicLinq. I would build where predicate in a string builder (build with some loop), and then pass it to `Where` that accepts predicate as string.

Comment: @pwas can you please suggest any good article in understanding DynamicLINQ? this is a new term for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why writing *"**a b**"* does not show any result is because the generated`SQL Query` is probably not like how you wanted it to be.

When there's only one keyword, such as *"**a**"* or *"**b**"* only, the `SQL query` would be like:

```sql
SELECT empName, bankCode, bankName, ...
FROM Employees
WHERE (empName LIKE '%a%') OR (bankCode LIKE '%a%') OR (bankName LIKE '%a%') ...
```

But when there's more than one keywords, such as *"**a b**"*, then the generated `SQL query` would be like:

```sql
SELECT empName, bankCode, bankName, ...
FROM Employees
WHERE ((empName LIKE '%a%') OR (bankCode LIKE '%a%') OR (bankName LIKE '%a%') ...) 
      AND ((empName LIKE '%b%') OR (bankCode LIKE '%b%') OR (bankName LIKE '%b%') ...) ...
```

Notice the `AND` operator there, what you wanted here is probably an ALL `OR` condition...

One way to easily achieve what you wanted is by using a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). 
Your updated example using `PredicateBuilder` would be something like this:

```cs
string[] keywords = toolStripTextBoxSearch.Text.Split(' ');
IQueryable<employee> query = db.employees;
Expression<Func<employee, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<employee>();

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
  predicate = predicate.Or(data => data.empName.Contains(keyword) || data.bank.bankCode.Contains(keyword) || data.bank.bankName.Contains(keyword) || data.department.deptName.Contains(keyword) || data.department.deptCode.ToString().Contains(keyword) || data.designation.desigText.Contains(keyword) || data.empBankAccount.Contains(keyword) || data.empBasicSalary.Value.ToString().Contains(keyword) || data.empIncomeTax.ToString().Contains(keyword) || data.empName.Contains(keyword) || data.empNTN.Contains(keyword) || data.empTicketNumber.Contains(keyword) || data.grade.gradeText.Contains(keyword));
}

dataGridViewEmployee.DataSource = query.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] keywords = toolStripTextBoxSearch.Text.Split(' ');
IQueryable<employee> query = db.employees;

query = query.Where(data => keywords.Contains(data.empName) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.bank.bankCode) || 
keywords.Contains(data.bank.bankName) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.department.deptName) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.department.deptCode.ToString()) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.designation.desigText) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empBankAccount) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empBasicSalary.Value.ToString()) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empIncomeTax.ToString()) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empName) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empNTN) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.empTicketNumber) ||  
keywords.Contains(data.grade.gradeText));
```

Answer (score 0):

On of the way is to use [DynamicLinq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
// ....

var predicateBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (var i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
{
    predicateBuilder.AppendFormat("empName.Contains(@{0}) 
                                    OR data.bank.bankCode.Contains(@{0})
                                    OR data.bank.bankName.Contains(@{0})
                                    OR ... and so on", i);

    if (i < keywords.Length - 1)
    {
        predicateBuilder.Append(" OR ");
    }
}

query = query.Where(predicateBuilder.ToString(), 
                    keywords.Cast<object>().ToArray());

var result = (IEnumerable<YourClass>)query.ToList();
```

**Cons**

1. Not strongly typed.
2. You can make mistake in Prop name,
3. Refactor-not-friendly - you have to remember that prop name has changed and do it manually in string.. for example

So use it, when nobody will gave you better solution. More on [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).